# How To Play YouTube Videos In The Background?

Tags: android, youtube-api, google-play, android-mediaplayer, android-youtube-api

I happened to see an application that allows me to minimize and play YouTube videos in the background. 
I know that the YouTube terms of service does not allow this. However, this app is not banned yet. Why are they not banned and how are they doing this?

[Link to Play Tube](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=play.tube.playtube.videotube.musictube.tubevideo&hl=vi)

Comment: It is not against YouTube terms of service to play videos in a floating window.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- They are using [TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams#TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY), that is why they require your "android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW". This would allow them to draw over other apps, while having their app in the "background". It is actually in the foreground.
- As for displaying the actual YT videos/comments part, well, they just start an [intent action view](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_VIEW) with a youtube link, that's all.

That covers how they do it.

As to why they are not banned? I believe it is because they are not actually letting you download any copyrighted material.